# Converting multidimensional array's values into a key value pair in a one-dimensional array while taking out a prefix out of one of the values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the following format:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 10820
            [option_name] => PREFIX_FIRST_OPT_KEY
            [option_value] => FIRST_OPT_VALUE
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 10821
            [option_name] => PREFIX_SECOND_OPT_KEY
            [option_value] => SECOND_OPT_VALUE
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 10824
            [option_name] => PREFIX_THIRD_OPT_KEY
            [option_value] => SECOND_OPT_VALUE
            [autoload] => yes


           )
    )
```

What is the appropriate function to use to get a one dimensional associative array with the following structure?

```
Array (
   [FIRST_OPT_KEY] => FIRST_OPT_VALUE
   [SECOND_OPT_KEY] => SECOND_OPT_VALUE
   [THIRD_OPT_KEY] => THIRD_OPT_VALUE
)
```

I only want to keep the indicated values as key value pairs in the new array and ignore the rest - `PREFIX_` is fixed length.

What I am doing right now:

```
foreach ( $the_original_array as $key => $value ) {
        $new_key = substr($the_original_array[$key]['option_name'], 7);
        $option_value = $the_original_array[$key]['option_value'];
            $new_array[$new_key] = $option_value;
}
```

but I feel there ought to be a cleaner/more efficient way of accomplishing this

Comment: You've shown what you have, what you want and what you've tried. Thank you.

Comment: What PHP Version do you have?

Comment: it will be running on lots of different hosts with lots of different configurations (its an import script included in my plugin) so there's no way for me to know ahead of time...just state the version required for your answer so I can make a decision on what's the best way forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of simulating array_column() if you aren't running PHP 5.5+

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($value)  {
            return substr($value['option_name'], 7);
        },
        $the_original_array
    ),
    array_map(
        function($value)  {
            return $value['option_value'];
        },
        $the_original_array
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have PHP >= 5.5:

To extract values:

```
$result = array_column($array, 'option_value', 'option_name');
```

Then to remove prefix:

```
$result = array_combine(
  array_map(
      function($k){
          return str_replace('PREFIX_', '', $k); 
      },
      array_keys($result)
  ), $result 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is valid, but it causes the data to be iterated over multiple times.  Assuming PHP < 5.5.0, using `array_reduce` will loop over the data only once, and return the same result:

```
$iterator = function($result, $record) {
    $key = substr($record['option_name'], 7);
    $result[$key] = $record['option_value'];
    return $result;
};
$newArray = array_reduce($original, $iterator, array());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `array_column` but for PHP < 5.5.0 what you have is about the best you can do, but you can use the `$value` that is generated by the `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $the_original_array as $value ) {
    $new_key = substr($value['option_name'], 7);
    $option_value = $value['option_value'];
    $new_array[$new_key] = $option_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think than foreach is good like:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($original_array as $item) {
    $index = str_replace('PREFIX_', '', $item['option_name']);
    $new[$index] = $item['option_value'];
}
```